# A sentence that contains all punctuations

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation

I am trying to teach punctuations to my little daughter. For that I am looking for a way to memories the punctuations and their correct usage. Particularly, I am looking for one or two sentences that contain all the punctuations with their correct usage. Can somebody please help me construct such a sentence; it would be helpful!

If there are more than one sentences, then it would be better if they are related to each other.

Punctuation marks: period, question mark, exclamation point, comma, colon, semicolon, apostrophe. There are others as well; however, I am happy with these seven.

Thank You!

Comment: Define "all punctuation".

Comment: @DoneWithThis. added the major ones.

Comment: Then there must be at least three sentences ;)

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Why teach your child something that would be extremely unusual in English? ("using all the punctuations"). By the way, punctuation is singular and we say punctuation marks. The idea though sounds like "over-parenting" to me. Your daughter is probably too young anyway. Under 10??

Comment: @Lambie Punctuation marks are not unusual. She is 11, in class 6. There is a chapter in English book.

Comment: Who said punctuation marks are unusual? Using them **all** in one sentence just is not all that likely in English.

Comment: @Lambie You misunderstood me. I am trying to memorize the punctuation marks and its usage, which becomes easy when one has to remember just one sentence. It is a handy trick to memorize and not forget for many years.

Comment: And you are deliberately misunderstanding me, it seems. We would not use all seven marks in one sentence. Especially the exclamation point and the question mark. Though some writers may use ?!. Very unusual.

Answer (score 1):

There must be at least three sentences, since the full-stop (period), question mark and exclamation mark all end a sentence (or utterance)

> — Girl: Dad, what's the naughtiest thing you've ever done?
>
> — Father: I once stole £5 from grandma's purse; I spent it on sweets.
>
> — Girl: Oh my gosh!

That dialogue has your seven punctuation marks, though the semicolon is a bit forced.

It's a bit useless, of course. Since each punctuation mark has several different uses, and this only illustrates one or two. I agree with Lambie... This is probably a bad idea.

Comment: That colon sounds like forced dialogue to me.

Comment: Totally forced. But separating the speaker from the dialogue is a valid use of the colon.

Comment: I appreciate the humour but feel sorry for the kid: A wee Japanese girl.

Comment: Have to deduct half a point for using the dash as a bullet point marker.  How about  "... you've ever done — well, maybe not the absolute naughtiest, but something you did as a kid."

Comment: Not a bullet point.  A mark of a new speaker.  See how James Joyce formats all direct quote (he doesn't use “ ”)  Probably redundant to the the explicit speaker names.

Answer (score 0):

I hope @James K allows me to borrow his script.

The girl said, "Dad, after hearing your story that you stole $9.20 from grandma's purse at 6:30 AM on 18 March 2003; you said it was for buying sweets, did I say 'Oh my gosh!'?"

More examples of uses of punctuation marks, like the following, are in [GBSE](https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-quotation-marks.html).

> Why does Shakespeare give Malcolm the banal question ‘O! by whom?’?